# AutoCompleteTextView getSelectionEnd() after rotation

Tags: java, android, subclass, autocompletetextview, super

The code below works, but it does not feel clean. The call to getSelectionEnd() needs to be done inside the Runnable, otherwise performFiltering will trigger before it has a value. The issue is that I need to call the overridden super function performFiltering and the only way I've figured out to do that is by making a stupid function which only purpose is calling the super function, see "superFiltering". How can I make this cleaner?

```
@Override
protected void performFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode) {    
    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String filteredText = text.toString();
            //Text must contain @
            if (filteredText.contains("@")) {
                filteredText = Utils.getAtRefText(filteredText, getSelectionEnd());
                superFiltering(filteredText, keyCode);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void superFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode) {
    super.performFiltering(text, keyCode);
}
```